Openstack Nova: PCI alias is not defined
I'm running Openstack Zed deployed with kolla-ansible 15.4.1. I'm facing a strange behavior:
I have a GPU on one of my compute node, and nova is configured to perform PCI passthrough. When I try to launch a VM most of the time I get an error: PCI alias tesla-v100 is not defined (HTTP 400)
But sometimes it succeed, the VM is created and the GPU is visible inside it.
I suppose there is a problem with filters. Seems like nova tries to launch the VM on random hypervisor, regardless if it has no GPU configured but sometimes it reach the right hypervisor. I tried different configurations but nothing works.
Any help would be much appreciated! :)
Bests,
MC

You should look into filters in more detail, there are couple of options how to create host aggregates (if necessary) which are targeted by your custom flavor.

I have an aggregate with extra specs matching the gpu flavor. I guess there's a conflict between aggregate_instance_extra_specs and pci_passthrough:alias filters.

Maybe you see in the debug logs why the scheduler decided what it decided. Another approach could be the placement aggregate. A few weeks ago I asked for instances to be placed specifically on one host, other filters didn't work as expected, but the placement traits did. Here's the thread.
